# Webmatrix backup - Need to know SQL table details to create a new database. Laptop Crashed

Tags: php, sql, webmatrix

I have created a website in webmatrix using php and mysql. My laptop got crashed yesterday now I am using another laptop. I have copied all the php files to my new laptop. But now I am in need to copy my mysql database to my new laptop. At least I need to know the table and fields details in my old hard disk. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: have you triedo to google this? https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=copy+mysql+databasae+from+one+server+to+another&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=wRAgU_mVLKOF8Qfr_oCgBA&gws_rd=cr

Comment: If you can access the files of your 'old' mysql installation then copy them to your new harddrive (to some temporary place and start a mysql server instance on them. This allows to create a clean "dump" using `mysqldump` which can then be loaded into another mysql server.

Comment: hi hek2mgl, I have tried but there is no solution for WebMatrix application.